# how can i get count of deleted rows with Typeorm delete function?

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2012, typeorm

using javascript and MS Sql Server.  i have a delete function that i want to return the number of rows deleted.

```
await getRepository(tableName, 'connection')
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .where(`timeCreated BETWEEN '${startDate}' and '${endDate}'`)
      .execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete result should have number of rows [affected](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/query-builder/result/DeleteResult.ts) property. However some database drivers may not support it, you can try it this way

```js
const deleteResult = await getRepository(tableName, 'connection')
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .delete()
      .where(`timeCreated BETWEEN '${startDate}' and '${endDate}'`)
      .execute();

const affectedRows = deleteResult.affected;
```